# How to add type hint to python factory_boy Factory classes?

Tags: python, factory, python-typing, metaclass, factory-boy

So we are working with some existing code where there is an implementation of factories classes from the [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) project which create instances of other classes for example

```
class TableFactory(Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Table

    id = LazyAttribute(lambda x: uuid4())
    color = SubFactory(ColorFactory)
    reference = 'WT9034'
    weight = 120
    height = 50
    length = 3
    width = 1
```

where the `Factory` base meta-class has a logic in its `__new__` method to dynamically instantiate a class using the model provided in the `Meta` class of the `TableFactory`. The `Table` model is a simple SQLAlchemy  class/model.

Since the produced classes are made dynamically I guess we cannot have static type hinting for the produced class types? Or can we somehow add this?

Comment: You could annotate the factory class to be generic over the model type it returns. I don't think you can easily have it look it up in `.Meta.model` though...

Comment: Wait, so does this dynamically create *instances* or *classes*?

Comment: @Aran-Fey so both, first it make a class and then an instance of it

Comment: Please provide the signature of the actual method you want to annotate and explain what it actually returns.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg what method? That is the issue the metaclass creates a class dynamically and then makes an instance of it, where can I annotate?

Comment: You are the one asking about type hints. A type hint is an annotation. I am asking **what** do you want to annotate. There is nothing in the code you provided that calls for type hints. **PS:** From what you wrote so far, it is not clear, what your actual problem is or what your desired outcome is.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg the factory class is a metaclass, it creates a class of whaterver model we provide it with and then instantiates it. I dont know which method you want me to add to help you ? That is my question actually. If I knew which  method to annotate I would not be asking, is not your comment self-cancelling?

Comment: I'm still not really sure if I understand the question. Naturally, in order to use a class as a type hint, the class must exist. So if you've already created the class then it's easy, and if you haven't then it's impossible.

Comment: I think the misunderstanding comes from the fact a particular framework for declarative and composable factories is being used: [factory-boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy). Defined factories implement a `create`, `build` and `stub` methods returning instances of the meta model (but not stub, which returns a stub model) and `create_batch`, `build_batch` and `stub_batch` that return lists of the former. Also, the `__new__` method can be configured to return from any of these three methods. But the methods are defined in the `Factory` superclass from the library.

Comment: Let me try this again: What is your actual problem and what is your desired outcome? Metaclass or not, you must have _some place_ in your code where _you think_ a type annotation is missing. Otherwise you would not as the question "How to add type hint [...]?" If not, rephrase your question, give an example of the problem your run into and what you actually want. Because right now, your question is incomplete.

Comment: @N1ngu So the question is "how do I annotate someone else's code"?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg maybe? I am very interested in how to benefit from type hints with this factories framework, but I am quite astray on how to do it. I just fear this is not yet possible https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/468

Comment: I think the problem here is that OP is trying to use a *dynamically* created class for *static* type annotations. That just doesn't make sense on a conceptual level. So I agree with @DaniilFajnberg - we need to see an actual function that OP wants to annotate. And then most likely the solution will be a TypeVar or a Protocol or something.

Comment: To add to what @Aran-Fey said: If you don't know which specific methods of the external base class are involved, that is fine. At least show an example where this causes _problems_ for you, e.g. `mypy` errors or missing auto-suggestions by PyCharm or what have you...  **PS:** It may very well be that you _can_ extend the base (meta-)class(es) with some custom type annotations, but for that we need to understand what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: @N1ngu Well, there we go again. What does "benefit from type hints" even mean in this context? What does that look like? Also the issue thread you showed, provides a bunch of workable suggestions to extend the base `Factory`. So I don't know why you would think it is not possible.

Comment: @N1ngu thank you the factory_boy sounds very similar to what we have. This is exactly it and that is where the problem comes from.

Comment: E.g. for the factory in the question, I'd like mypy to infer that `TableFactory.create()` will yield a `Table` type.

Comment: @N1ngu Not much you can do there, I think. Outside of `def create() -> Table`, I'm not sure if there's anything else. `class TableFactory(metaclass=FactoryMeta[Table]):` might work I guess?

Comment: Actually, `class TableFactory(Factory[Table]):` is also an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming OP's concrete problem is that he is getting errors from the type checker when trying to use instances of the factory in his test code.

Example:

```py
obj = TableFactory()
print(obj.reference)
```

This will create a type error like this with pylance:

> Can not access member "reference" for type TableFactory.

### Solution 1

A quick solution is to type annotate the assignment with the correct type. However, this does not work with the class alone, you need to also use one of the instantiation methods like create() or build() to create the object:

```py
obj: Table = TableFactory.create()
print(obj.reference)
```

This works fine, but requires you to annotate all factory assignments in that particular way, which can get repetitive and make the code harder to read.

### Solution 2

A better solution is add the type annotation to the factory class itself. This can be done by creating a mixin which has the generic type annotation and use it to compose a new factory class.

Here is how this would work:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

import factory

T = TypeVar('T')

class BaseMetaFactory(Generic[T], factory.base.FactoryMetaClass):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> T:
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class TableFactory(factory.Factory, metaclass=BaseMetaFactory[Table]):
    class Meta:
        model = Table
    
    ...
```

As added bonus this mixin can be used create annotated version of all our factory classes.

For a more in depth discussion on different workarounds for this problem please also see the [related issue](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/468) on the factory boy repo.

Comment: Just beware about the stubs generation strategy: `TableFactory()` can return `factory.base.StubObject` instances instead of your class. IMHO it is saner to type and restrict yourself to the explicit `.create()` and `.build()` (and `.stub()`) factory methods instead of the magic meta factory `__call__`.